# UITableView does not show data correctly in my custom cell UILabel and reuse problem

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I create my custom cell class and design my user interface with the code and constraints (I have 2 `UILabels` that hold my data in each row). I register my **customcell** class in the main **viewController** and load data in the `tableview`.

The problem is one of my `UILabels` fills with data but the second one not show its data until I scroll the table view or click right on that row. See images.

**Before Scroll**

[image]

**After scroll**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class ProjectDetailsCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var key   : String?
    var value : String?

    var keyContainerView : UIView = {
        var containerView = UIView()
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.867, green: 0.867, blue: 0.867, alpha: CGFloat(1))
        return containerView
    }()

    var keyView : UILabel = {
        var keyTextView = UILabel()
        keyTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        keyTextView.font = UIFont(name: "IRANSansWeb", size: 13)
        keyTextView.textAlignment = .center
        return keyTextView
    }()

    var valueView : UILabel = {
        var valueTextView = UILabel()
        valueTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        valueTextView.textAlignment = .center
        valueTextView.font = UIFont(name: "IRANSansWeb", size: 12)
        //valueTextView.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: CGFloat(1))
        return valueTextView
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(valueView)
        self.addSubview(keyContainerView)
        keyContainerView.addSubview(keyView)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42).isActive = true
        keyContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        keyContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        keyContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4).isActive = true
        keyContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        keyView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.keyContainerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        keyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.keyContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        keyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.keyContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        keyView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.keyContainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        valueView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.keyContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        valueView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        valueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        valueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let key = key {
            keyView.text = key + value!
        }

        if let value = value {
            valueView.text = value
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

here is my data source code that populate the data array :

```
for i in 0..<self.detailsArray.count {
            // Populate our array list with the real data and restart the tableview
            self.dict = self.detailsArray[i]
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "شماره سفارش", value: String(self.dict["Id"] as! Int)))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "قیمت", value: self.dict["Price"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "زمان و تاریخ سفارش", value: self.dict["DateTime"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "نام و نام خانوادگی کارفرما", value: self.dict["UserInformation"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "شماره تماس کارفرما", value: self.dict["UserPhone"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "نام خدمات دهنده", value: self.dict["ContractorInformation"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "شماره خدمات دهنده", value: self.dict["ContractorPhone"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "تاریخ درخواست خدمات", value: self.dict["ServiceDate"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "ساعت درخواست خدمات", value: self.dict["ServiceTime"] as? String))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "مقدار کار", value: (self.dict["WorkAmmount"] as? String)! + " " + (self.dict["WorkUnit"] as? String)!))
            self.dataList.append(DetailsCellData.init(key: "هزینه تخمینی (ریال)", value: self.dict["EstimatedPrice"] as? String))
            self.tableview.reloadData()
```

here is my table view delegates code

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (dataList.count < 11){
        return 0
    } else {
        return dataList.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectDetailsCustomCell
    cell.key = self.dataList[indexPath.row].key
    cell.value = self.dataList[indexPath.row].value
    return cell
}
```

Comment: If you could add your tableviewdatasource code to the question, that will help.

Comment: can you share the code, maybe its due to the layout subview.

Comment: @PeteMorris i added the data source code to the question

Comment: @AjaySinghThakur i added some other code to the question .

Comment: yes you are doing table view reload after populating data but you are setting the constraint in tableviewcell init method which is update after viewdidlayoutSubviews() which is called when you scroll or touch the tableview cell. please read about setting the constrain by code more

Comment: @AjaySinghThakur so what should i do bro ?

Comment: @AjaySinghThakur i don't think so i put break point in my code and see that the init method start before layoutSubviews method that put data in the labels :(

Comment: init method called before layoutsubview true,but constraints update on layoutsuview, put viewdidlayout() method in viewcontroller check it called after viewdidload and print any view frame who is using constriant.

Comment: If this is on iOS and by dataSource code you mean that this is the cellForRowAtIndexPath function then you are doing this incorrectly. You are not meant to populate the entire array in cellForRow, but give each cell what it needs to populate itself.

Comment: please show tablview delegate code.

Comment: @AjaySinghThakur ok

Comment: @AjaySinghThakur i added the table view delegates methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    updateLayout()
}

func updateLayout() {
    if let key = key {
        keyView.text = key + value!
    }

    if let value = value {
        valueView.text = value
    }
}
```

try this way, also add a line here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectDetailsCustomCell
    cell.key = self.dataList[indexPath.row].key
    cell.value = self.dataList[indexPath.row].value
    cell.updateLayout()
    return cell
}
```